# Git: is it safe to rebase a branch already merged?

Tags: git, version-control, merge, branching-and-merging, rebase

Is it safe to `rebase` local (private) `feature branch`, if it's already merged to `master`, and I decide to tweak the feature later by `rebasing` the `feature branch` on the current tip of `master`? I know it's death sentence to `rebase` a shared branch, but is it safe in this case, as long as branch itself is *private*? As far as I can see, `rebasing` in this scenario will only add those diverged changes in `master` on top of the *common history* plus some local changes of the branch totally private to me. So no harm should be done, right? Is there any special scenarios, where this pattern would cause problems?

**EDIT**

One concern to think about is, if I perform `interactive rebase` on a feature branch to clean up the commit history, for example

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

and this branch has already been merged to master, then both branches introduces same changes with different commits right? And this of course is not desired.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a feature branch that was merged to `master`,
and then more commits were added in both `master` and the feature branch.
That is:

```
      A---B---C---D---E topic
     /         \
D---E---F---G---M---X---Y master
```

When you rebase the feature branch on `master`,
that will practically insert the commits that were added in master,
in front of the commits that you added locally in the feature branch.
Exactly as you wrote yourself.
That should work fine.
You will get:

```
      A---B---C           D'---E' topic
     /         \         /
D---E---F---G---M---X---Y master
```

This pattern should not cause any harm.
There's just the usual risk with any rebasing,
that your commits in the feature branch may conflict with the changes that were added in master.
That has nothing to do with the "pattern",
that's just the usual risk of any rebase and merge operation.

I'm also going to quote an addendum by [@VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc):

> Not only the pattern will not cause any harm, but it will help minimizing the number of commits to replay by the `git rebase`, while integrating the latest `master` commits into your `feature` environment, helping you to resolve conflicts locally before merging `feature` to `master` later on. ([stackoverflow.com/a/804178/6309](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804115/when-do-you-use-git-rebase-instead-of-git-merge/804178#804178)).

Comment: Not only the pattern will not cause any harm (+1), but it will help minimizing the number of commits to replay by the `git rebase`, while integrating the latest `master` commits into your `feature` environment, helping you to resolve conflicts locally *before* merging `feature` to `master` later on. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/804178/6309).

Comment: Thanks @VonC, incorporated that in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Like documentation says :

Rebase is a good way to "synchronise" by take care to save your current commit, apply commits on branch you rebase, and then apply saved commits.

Here the scenario :

```
      A---B---C topic
     /
D---E---F---G master
```

From this point, the result of either of the following commands:

git rebase master
git rebase master topic
would be:

```
              A'--B'--C' topic
             /
D---E---F---G master
```

Don't forget that rebase, like merge, should leads to merge conflicts, it's Git life.